# "Invalid base64 data" error when using tramp

Tags: tramp, ssh

I'm using an Intel Edison, and I want to edit files on there with Emacs.  I can connect to the device with tramp, using several methods and explore using dired.  But trying to visit a file gives an error "Invalid base64 data".

Answer (score 4):

The Edison didn't have some of the utilities tramp needs (base64, uuencode).  Apparently tramp sends a perl script if it can't find them, but it did not work.  It turns out that even when using methods like `scp`, tramp tries to do inline transfers when the file is below a size threshold, `tramp-copy-size-limit`.  I can do

```
(setq tramp-copy-size-limit nil)
```

to force "external copy" (i.e. using `scp`) always.

---

New problem: multi-hops don't allow `scp`.  E.g. `/ssh:proxy|scp:user@remote:file` is invalid, which in turn means that external copy is not used for multi-hops.  I guess I'll have to set up an ssh proxy for that:

```
Host dev # the edison, on another network
User root # on dev
HostName 10.251.1.112 # LAN IP of dev
# nc must be installed on proxy
ProxyCommand ssh -Aq jpkotta@proxy "nc -q 1 %h %p"
```

`/scp:dev:file` or `/ssh:dev:file` with `tramp-copy-size-limit` set to `nil`.

Comment: Yes for files < 10240 bytes, set the limit to nil to force TRAMP to use the specified external method. Otherwise TRAMP defaults to inline methods.

Comment: this didn't help